# Visual Studio ItemsTemplate - $safeitemrootname$ is not doing what expected

Tags: visual-studio, parameters, itemtemplate, visual-studio-templates

I'm trying to create an ItemTemplate with multiple files. So far, so good. Both of my files are created and they have the right name. Now, one of them is named as the user entered. The other must use that name. I think that's what `$safeitemrootname$` is supposed to do. How ever I get the same result as `$safeitemname$`. How can I do?

Thanks